# What does that mean, how is it called? class MyClass : something, something2{ ... }

Tags: c#, class, documentation

I have came around this several time, but I have no idea, how it is called, nor what it is, what it does.

```
class MyClass : something, something2{ ... }
```

Can you point me to the right direction please? Some documentation etc.

Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion - start from [OOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming)

Comment: read about Inheritance in OOP

Comment: What you mean what does it called, Inheritance? I think you are starting to explore language from wrong direction.

Comment: The colon points to inheritance and the fact that two names follow to Interface (as C# doesn't have multiple inheritance.) - This site is not for tutorials or introductions to basic language elements though..

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was looking for the word Inheritance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this example scenario:

```
interface IComponent
{
    void DoStuff();
}

interface ITitledComponent : IComponent
{
    string Title { get; }
}

abstract class ComponentBase : IComponent
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class MyComponent : ComponentBase, ITitledComponent
{
    public string Title => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The line `class MyComponent : ComponentBase, ITitledComponent` is saying, that the class `MyComponent` **must** inherit the class `ComponentBase` and implement the interface `ITitledComponent` with all their internal definitions.